# Core.async: Take all values from collection of promise-chans

Tags: clojure, core.async

Consider a dataset like this:

```
(def data [{:url "http://www.url1.com" :type :a}
           {:url "http://www.url2.com" :type :a}
           {:url "http://www.url3.com" :type :a}
           {:url "http://www.url4.com" :type :b}])
```

The contents of those URL's should be requested in parallel. Depending on the item's :type value those contents should be parsed by corresponding functions. The parsing functions return collections, which should be concatenated, once all the responses have arrived.

So let's assume that there are functions `parse-a` and `parse-b`, which both return a collection of strings when they are passed a string containing `HTML` content.

It looks like `core.async` could be a good tool for this. One could either have separate channels for each item ore one single channel. I'm not sure which way would be preferable here. With several channels one could use transducers for the postprocessing/parsing. There is also a special `promise-chan` which might be proper here.

Here is a code-sketch, I'm using a callback based `HTTP kit` function. Unfortunately, I could not find a generic solution inside the go block.

```
(defn f [data] 
  (let [chans (map (fn [{:keys [url type]}] 
                     (let [c (promise-chan (map ({:a parse-a :b parse-b} type)))] 
                       (http/get url {} #(put! c %))
                       c))
                   data)
        result-c (promise-chan)] 
    (go (put! result-c (concat (<! (nth chans 0))
                               (<! (nth chans 1))
                               (<! (nth chans 2))
                               (<! (nth chans 3)))))
    result-c))
```

The result can be read like so:

```
(go (prn (<! (f data))))
```

Comment: What's your question, specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that `promise-chan` does more harm than good here. The problem is that most of `core.async` API (`a/merge`, `a/reduce` etc.) relies on fact that channels will close at some point, `promise-chan`s in turn never close.

So, if sticking with `core.async` is crucial for you, the better solution will be not to use `promise-chan`, but ordinary channel instead, which will be closed after first `put!`:

```
...
(let [c (chan 1 (map ({:a parse-a :b parse-b} type)))]
  (http/get url {} #(do (put! c %) (close! c)))
  c)
...
```

At this point, you're working with closed channels and things become a bit simpler. To collect all values you could do something like this:

```
;; (go (put! result-c (concat (<! (nth chans 0))
;;                            (<! (nth chans 1))
;;                            (<! (nth chans 2))
;;                            (<! (nth chans 3)))))
;; instead of above, now you can do this:
(->> chans
     async/merge
     (async/reduce into []))
```

**UPD** (below are my personal opinions):

Seems, that using `core.async` channels as promises (either in form of `promise-chan` or channel that closes after single `put!`) is not the best approach. When things grow, it turns out that `core.async` API overall is (you may have noticed that) not that pleasant as it could be. Also there are several [unsupported constructs](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/wiki/Go-Block-Best-Practices#unsupported-constructs-and-other-limitations-in-go-blocks), that may force you to write less idiomatic code than it could be. In addition, there is no built-in error handling (if error occurs within `go`-block, `go`-block will silently return `nil`) and to address this you'll need to come up with something of your own (reinvent the wheel). Therefore, if you need promises, I'd recommend to use specific library for that, for example [`manifold`](https://github.com/ztellman/manifold) or [`promesa`](https://github.com/funcool/promesa).

Comment: Actually in the meanwhile I came to more or less the solution you are proposing. This worked smoothly until I decided to add error handling to it. I might use plain promises instead.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted this functionality as well because I really like `core.async` but I also wanted to use it in certain places like traditional `JavaScript` promises. I came up with a solution using macros. In the code below, `<?` is the same thing as `<!` but it throws if there's an error. It behaves like [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in that it returns a `vector` of all the returned values from the channels if they all are successful; otherwise it will return the first error (since `<?` will cause it to throw that value).

```
(defmacro <<? [chans]
  `(let [res# (atom [])]
     (doseq [c# ~chans]
       (swap! res# conj (serverless.core.async/<? c#)))
     @res#))
```

If you'd like to see the full context of the function it's located on [GitHub](https://github.com/dehli/serverless/blob/0c1cf46576cb3df5696d4d598fddf467a6fb9b23/src/serverless/core/async.clj). It's heavily inspired from David Nolen's [blog post](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/08/31/asynchronous-error-handling).

Answer (score 0):

**Use [pipeline-async](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/pipeline-async) in `async.core` to launch asynchronous operations** like `http/get` concurrently while delivering the result in the same order as the input:

```
(let [result (chan)] 
  (pipeline-async 
    20 result
    (fn [{:keys [url type]} ch]
      (let [parse ({:a parse-a :b parse-b} type)
            callback #(put! ch (parse %)(partial close! ch))]  
        (http/get url {} callback)))
    (to-chan data))
  result)
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still looking at this, adding on to the answer by @OlegTheCat:

You can use a separate channel for errors.

```
(:require [cljs.core.async :as async]
            [cljs-http.client :as http])
(:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]])

(go (as-> [(http/post <url1> <params1>)
           (http/post <url2> <params2>)
           ...]
          chans
          (async/merge chans (count chans))
          (async/reduce conj [] chans)
          (async/<! chans)
          (<callback> chans)))
```